# Filtering Repeater in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, repeater

I'm new to ASP.NET and C# and I am having difficulty filtering my SQL data within a Repeater Control using AJAX.

I have the SQL data showing on my page but I need to find a way to filter the data using AJAX.  I'm not sure if I need to add code to my .cs file or can update through JavaScript/JQuery.

The code for Repeater is below:

```
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnItemCommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">
        <ItemTemplate>
           <div class="PhysicianDetails">
                    <span><%#Eval("LastName")%>,</span>
                    <span><%#Eval("FirstName")%></span>
                    <p><%#Eval("Language")%></p>
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="View Profile" CommandName="ViewProfile" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ContactID")%>' />
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

The code for input fields and DropDownList which I want to filter the data within Repeater Control.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>

            <div id="sidebar">
                <h3>Refine Your Search</h3>
                <p>Provider First Name:</p>
                <input type="text" runat="server" name="name" value=" " placeholder="Search by First Name" />
                <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="GO" />

                <p>Provider Last Name:</p>
                <input type="text" name="name" value=" " placeholder="Search by Last Name" />
                <%--Last Name<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>--%>
                <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="GO" />

                <p>Search by Language:</p>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="Languages" DataValueField="Languages"></asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:DB %>" SelectCommand="Select DISTINCT Language From Languages"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="GO" />
            </div>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I'd avoid UpdatePanel, and simply use JavaScript on the client (using AJAX requests to ASHX or Web API if I need additional data from the server).

Comment: What would be the easiest way to have JavaScript manipulate data within repeater control?  Sorry, I'm a noob!

Comment: Your repeater (server side) renders HTML (to the client side), once there, whenever the client attempts to filter the data, make an ajax call to the server instead of doing your regular postback. Once the server delivers the resultant data asynchronously to the client, manipulate that result at the client side. You can find many samples online.

Comment: Also, if you are new to asp.net and c# I may suggest you to explore and learn [asp.net MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) instead of webforms.